# Anybody out there having success with the NWorkspace pattern?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I've just begun to delve into my first experiments with Domain Drive Design and I'm taking advantage of the NWorkspace pattern. This pattern seems to make a lot of sense however I haven't been able to find very many examples of places this pattern has been successfully used or even publicly documented. Before I get to far into my implementation I would like to know if anybody has had success using this pattern or whether somebody could point me to any references where NWorkspace has been used in any open source project that I could learn from. Also are there better or more well known alternatives to this pattern that I should know about?

**Brief background on NWorkspace**

For those who may not be familiar with NWorkspace, it is a pattern introduced by [Jimmy Nisson's](http://jimmynilsson.com/blog/) which abstracts query and persistance responsibilities. In his book Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns, Jimmy Nilsson shows how NWorkspace can be used to abstract the infrastructure portions of a DDD Repository as well as provide a mechanism to perform cross Repository atomicity with regard to persistence.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like he's recommending separate interfaces for read and write repositories.
I don't have experience with the pattern described, but I would recommend **not** having cross-repository transactions.  Instead, I would suggest a few solutions popular amongst the DDD community (Eric Evans, Udi Dahan, Greg Young) that have really helped me:

1. Always use eager loading on your aggregate roots.  Then you don't need cross-repository atomicity, and figuring out what's changed when you persist the object is a lot easier.
2. Use separate classes for writing (i.e. domain classes) and reading (i.e. your viewmodel).  Create view model repositories that retrieve viewmodels directly from the database (instead of mapping domain objects to view model classes).

See if implementing the above 2 things simplifies your design.

Comment: The second suggestion seems a bit foreign to me, sounds almost like ViewModel is being treated as an aggregate root. Could you point me to any resources that discuss this further? I haven't been able to find much current discussion on DDD other than a little here on Stack Overflow so any other resources would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure thing.  The main dudes you want to read up on are Udi Dahan and Greg Young.  They've got video talks at skillsmatter.com that are highly recommended.  Also check out cqrsinfo.com.  The technique I'm describing in #2 above is called CQRS (command query responsibility segregation).  It was invented by the aforementioned Greg Young.

Comment: The basic idea of CQRS is that your domain classes (at least publicly) are mostly methods with no public setters and few public getters.  All reading is done via the viewmodel, which are pretty much all public getters and setters.

Comment: Interesting, I'll definitely look into these topics. I've heard of CQRS quite a while back I've used it as a guiding principle in method design but the idea of reducing the amount that the domain model acts as a store of data that backs a ViewModel makes sense although I'm not sure how this impacts the importance of the Domain itself. So basically if the domain model is only invoked for write purposes it has limited life expectancy and thus most of it should be able to be written a chain of method calls instead of modeling the domain in a object oriented way... Well just my initial thoughts.

Comment: You still load the domain model from some sort of data store in order to invoke more methods on it after it's been initially persisted.  To boil it down (and slightly oversimplify), your domain model is all void methods and your viewmodel is all getters.  It's not really that cut and dry in practice, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Hmmm, I appreciate your input but it's still not clicking for me. Perhaps after I research more on the resources you offered it might start making more sense. For right now it seems like quite a shift from how I've seen most apps developed and I don't see any benefits in making the domain objects something that are write-only.

Comment: The benefit will probably become obvious to you when you start to run into friction with what you need in the UI (like if you need data from 2 aggregates in one grid) vs. how you want to model domain behavior.  It wasn't obvious to me until I got more experience.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tend to mark topics as answered when they are truly answered (maybe a bit strict). Essentially your answer said that you don't really have experience with the NWorkspace pattern but you did give some reasons why you disagreed with it. I up-voted you because I do value your input but I would like to keep the question open to give somebody else the opportunity to share their experience using NWorkspace. I would also accept and answer from somebody who could give a convincing argument that nobody has tried it otherwise I'll answer the question my self eventually.

Comment: That's cool with me.  Just wanted to make sure you were leaving unanswered intentionally.